# Leave the client hanging while server creates file for download

Tags: node.js, rest, express, download

On a server with Node.js + Express I have an API with the purpose of exporting a million records from DB to file, which then needs to be downloaded by the client. How I am doing it now: create the file while the client waits for a response, which takes around 2 minutes, and when the file is ready do `res.download(file)`.

It works fine locally, but when deployed I am getting a Gateway 504 error. Initially I tried to pipe data to the client while going through the DB cursor, but it was too slow so I implemented a multithreading mechanism, and piping it is not possible anymore.

Is there a way I can work around this? Perhaps by opening the response stream to the client but without sending anything until the file is ready to be downloaded. Not sure if this is possible?

Comment: if you can create export as a stream then you simply pipe that into your response object, where the client don't have to wait until the complete file is exported, something like this : https://nikgrozev.com/2017/05/10/mongo-query-to-CSV-download-expressjs/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as I stated in the question I can't stream it like that

Comment: Hey, if this is still relevant - what's the gateway you're using? Meaning where is it deployed?